# How can in ad in Pycharm 2 cloned repositories from github(interdependent) under the same project

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm cloning two separate repositories from github:

1. a framework
2. some modules that are based on the framework

How can I add both of them in Pycharm projects, so the modules (in the second package) recognize the files(imports) from the framework(1).

Answer (score 0):

You can have PyCharm including more directories to `PYHTONPATH` by adding a content root.

Open the menu entry File -> Settings. Select Project: (your project), then Project Structure. On the right pane, you can add the root of the second repository as another content root.

In the run configuration, make sure that "Add content roots to PYTHONPATH" is checked (this should be checked by default).

Content roots must be disjoint (i.e. the second repository should not be checked out in a subdirectory of the first). If this is not the case, there is also the option of fine tuning your `PYTHONPATH` by marking individual directories as *source* in the above Project Structure window (related run configuration setting "Add source roots to PYTHONPATH").